# input submit should open in parent window

Tags: html, input, window, submit, parent

I have a little `<form>` in HTML, (for logging into something), but the page with the form in in an `<iframe>` …

When you click the submit button (`<input type="submit" value="submit">`) , it should open the page where you are logged in in the parent page… How can i do this ?

Maybe possible by using instead of `<input>` just `<a>` , if that's possible ?

Comment: `<form target="_parent" ...>`

Comment: @RobW Doesn't work...

Comment: Works fine: `data:text/html,<iframe src="data:text/html,<form target=_parent><input type=submit name=x value=y></form>"></iframe>`. If the frame is from a different origin, a new tab will be opened though.

Comment: @RobW did something wrong :) it worked ! thanks !